# Invalid URL Format For Media Streaming - Why? What could I be doing wrong?

Tags: python, flask, twilio

```py
from flask import Flask, request, Response
import requests
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Play, Start, Stream

from twilio.rest import Client
import time
import os
from google.cloud import speech_v1 as speech
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import types
import threading
import queue
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

#Google Cloud Credentials environment variable
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = './google_credentials.json'

# Twilio credentials
account_sid = ['TWILIO_SID']
auth_token = ['TWILIO_AUTH']
twilio_client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()

# Create a queue to store audio chunks
audio_chunks_queue = queue.Queue()

# A simple in-memory structure to store call associations
# In production, you might want to use a database
call_associations = {}

response = None

@app.route("/incoming_call", methods=['POST'])
def handle_incoming_call():
    """Responds to incoming calls and sets up segmented recording of inbound audio."""
    response = VoiceResponse()

    start = Start()
    stream = Stream(url='wss://b32e-2603-8081-4c00-3a7c-2d64-d183-b6e6-f523.ngrok-free.app/stream_audio')
    start.append(stream)
    response.append(start)

    twiml_response_str = str(response)
    print("Generated TwiML Response:\n", twiml_response_str)

         
    print("incoming call")
    return Response(str(response), mimetype='text/xml')

@app.route("/stream_audio", methods=['POST'])
def stream_audio():
    """Receive streamed audio from Twilio and add it to the queue."""
    print("Audio is streaming")
    audio_data = request.get_data()
    audio_chunks_queue.put(audio_data)
    return ('', 204)
```

The desired result is to get the print statement 'Audio is streaming', but I get this instead from Twilio Dashboard

Message

Invalid URL.

Error Description

### Error - 11100 ### Invalid URL format The format of the provided URL is invalid.

Possible Solutions
Make sure you submit a fully qualified URL including:

protocol (http:// or https://)
hostname
file path
properly url-encoded query parameters
Twilio must be able to reach this URL over the public Internet.

Possible Causes
Bad URL for phone number configuration
Bad URL passed to outgoing call REST request
Bad URL in Play or Redirect Verb Body
Bad URL provided for a verb's action attribute
No URL provided in Record verb action attribute when modifying a live call
Unsupported characters in auth portion of URL

Should I be using https instead? Using https gives me the same error. Or do I need to import a library to use wss?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are specifying a `ws` server endpoint, but your code only accepts `http` at that endpoint. This is why Twilio can't stream audio to it. This [blog post](https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text) explains how to build something that appears similar to what you are building.

From it, I got this sample file that coordinates both, and `http` and `ws` endpoints:

```py
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Handle Web Socket Connection
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
console.log("New Connection Initiated");

   ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    const msg = JSON.parse(message);
    switch (msg.event) {
      case "connected":
        console.log(`A new call has connected.`);
        break;
      case "start":
        console.log(`Starting Media Stream ${msg.streamSid}`);
        break;
      case "media":
        console.log(`Receiving Audio...`)
        break;
      case "stop":
        console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
        break;
    }
  });

};

//Handle HTTP Request
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World");

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");

  res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Start>
      <Say>I will stream the next 60 seconds of audio through your websocket</Say>
      <Pause length="60" />
    </Response>
  `);
});

console.log("Listening at Port 8080");
server.listen(8080);
```